# "Script Error" in IE8 when trying to display huge data with expand-collapse functionality

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, coldfusion

I have a report to display on UI with +- functionality(javascript coded). The code is written in ColdFusion. The data is huge; around 15 columns and number of td's tr's. **It displays fine in higher versions of IE, but getting the script error(screen shot attached) in** **IE8**. Additionally, since we have so much data to display the amount of huge TD elements are getting out of control for IE8(screen shot attached).
I believe IE8 is not supporting the script i have put in for expand/collapse functionality. 
Since most of the users use IE8, i was little worried. Any idea how should i handle this?
Here is the small code snippet:

```
<cfset orgcounter =0>
<cfloop list="#orgList#" index="tempOrg" delimiters="|">
<cfset orgcounter = orgcounter + 1>

<td style="border-bottom:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;" nowrap>                          
        <a href="javascript://Open/close org details" onclick="showIt('row#orgcounter#');" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">
                <img class="mydiv" src="#Request.Library.Images.URL#plusminus/minus.gif" border="0" id="minusrow#orgcounter#" style="display:none;" align="left">
                <img src="#Request.Library.Images.URL#plusminus/plus.gif" border="0" id="plusrow#orgcounter#" align="left">
                        #tempOrg#
        </a>
        <!--- Display OrgAdmin --->
        <br><font style="font-size:10px;padding-left:20px;font-weight:normal">
                #structMetrics[theorgname]["~total"]["OrgAdmin"]#
            </font>                         

</td>
```

Here "ShowIt" is the JS function for Expand/Collapse.

JS Code:

```
function showIt(thename)    {
    var theMinus = 'minus'+thename;
    var thePlus = 'plus'+thename;

    var oObject = document.all.item(thename);

    if (oObject != null){
       if (oObject.length != null){
          for(i = 0; i < oObject.length; i++){
            statusDisplay = oObject(i).style.display;

            if(statusDisplay=='')   {
                oObject(i).style.display='none';
                document.getElementById(theMinus).style.display='none';
                document.getElementById(thePlus).style.display='';
            }
            else    {
                oObject(i).style.display='';
                document.getElementById(theMinus).style.display='';
                document.getElementById(thePlus).style.display='none';
            }
          }
       }
       else{
            statusDisplay = oObject.style.display;
              if(statusDisplay=='') {
                    oObject.style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById(theMinus).style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById(thePlus).style.display='';
                }
                else    {
                    oObject.style.display='';
                    document.getElementById(theMinus).style.display='';
                    document.getElementById(thePlus).style.display='none';
                }
       }
    } 

    return true;
}
```

[image: Error]

[image: UI]

Original report on UI look like this:
[image]

Comment: Don't show us the output, show us the code that generates the faulty JS. That said, this sounds like a JS question not a CFML question? If you're getting JS errors, you need to look at the JS code, not the CFML code.

Comment: And which "line 62" is it referring to, and what troubleshooting have you done so far? Have you inspected what object the error is talking about, and verified it is what you think it is?

Comment: If you need to display more data than the browser can handle, consider outputting to excel instead.

Comment: Try dropping jQuery into the app and using it to handle hiding/showing. Would help eliminate browser specific issues like this.

Comment: @AdamCameron I think its cute you think you can inspect objects in IE 8. :D

Comment: @ScottStroz hahaha. Well I mean with like some arcane combination of alerts() and tea leaves and wishful thinking.